# Abnormal AVAudioPlayer playback speed on iOS 8

Tags: ios, avaudioplayer

When I played a local audio file using AVAudioPlayer, I found a strange behavior where the audio player is playing at a speed roughly 0.04% faster than the normal speed. I did not change the playback speed of the player at all.

I have this problem on an iPadMini with iOS 8 and also on iPad Simulators, but on an iPad Air with iOS 7 such problem does not occur.

To show the problem, I wrote some simple code which periodically compares player.currentTime with the system clock:

```
- (void) viewDidLoad
{
    self.audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:
                            [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"test" withExtension:@"mp3"] error:nil];
    [self.audioPlayer prepareToPlay];
}
- (IBAction) onPlayButtonClicked:(id)sender
{
    [self.audioPlayer play];
    self.playBeginTime = [NSDate timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate];

    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:4.0 target:self selector:@selector(report)
                                   userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}
- (void) report
{
    NSTimeInterval elapsedSystemTime = [NSDate timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate] - self.playBeginTime;
    NSTimeInterval playerTime = self.audioPlayer.currentTime;

    printf ( “\nElapsedSystemTime(%.5f) - PlayerTime(%.5f) = Latency(%.5f)”,
            elapsedSystemTime,  playerTime,  elapsedSystemTime - playerTime);
}
```

The output goes like this (on an iPadMini with iOS 8):

```
ElapsedSystemTime(4.00141) - PlayerTime(3.95601) = Latency(0.04540)
ElapsedSystemTime(8.00133) - PlayerTime(7.95741) = Latency(0.04391)
ElapsedSystemTime(12.00131) - PlayerTime(11.95896) = Latency(0.04235)
...
ElapsedSystemTime(112.00131) - PlayerTime(111.99884) = Latency(0.00247)
ElapsedSystemTime(116.00137) - PlayerTime(116.00068) = Latency(0.00069)
ElapsedSystemTime(120.00133) - PlayerTime(120.00209) = Latency(-0.00075)
...
ElapsedSystemTime(232.00133) - PlayerTime(232.04685) = Latency(-0.04552)
ElapsedSystemTime(236.00132) - PlayerTime(236.04853) = Latency(-0.04721)
ElapsedSystemTime(240.00132) - PlayerTime(240.05002) = Latency(-0.04870)
```

Notice the latency value starts with 0.045s initially but after playing the audio for 240 seconds, the latency has decreased to a value of -0.0487s.
This shows that the audio player is actually playing at a speed noticeably higher than 1X speed.

Does anyone have the same problem? Is there any way to solve it?

Thank you all,

Roy

Comment: What issue is this causing?

Comment: I'm working on an app that heavily depends on the system clock to synchronize audio and other stuff (such as a metronome and 2D animations.) Since the audio player's playback speed is not consistent with the system clock, there are some noticeable delays after a song is played for several minutes, and such defects exaggerate over time.